# Is there a particular name for repeating-word adverb?

Tags: adverbs

I wonder if there is any particular name for those repeating-word adverbs (such as すくすく or ころころ).
It seems to me that there are quite a number of them and they seem somehow special.

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/